# FirebaseDatabase.getIntance() throwing null pointer exception : Firebase Database component not present

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

`FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();` is Throwing a NullPointerException: Firebase component is not present.

Tried by updating a different version of Firebase database library

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Firebase Database component is not present.
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Unknown Source:11)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:120)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:60)
        at com.vkeel.Dependencies.init(Dependencies.java:52)
        at com.vkeel.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:15)
        at com.vkeel.ui.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
```

Comment: Hello Gautam, Can you share your code where you have used Firebase database

Comment: André Kool - I know what is NullPointerException, but in my case the FirebaseDatbase library throwing null pointer when I am trying to Instantiate it.

Comment: @GautamKumar did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use latest gradle tool and google service

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```